# Function font_back - Error

Tags: python, string, if-statement, compiler-errors

This is a question from http://codingbat.com/, where I am practicing my new skills on Python. So what I want is to given a string, return a new string where the first and last chars have been exchange (the first char is now the last and vice-versa).

Here is my code:

```
def front_back(str): 
  if len(str)==1:   #if str is 'a', it should return 'a'
    return str

  else:    # len(str) is greater than one
    first = str[0]        # first character
    last = str[-1]        # last charater
    new = last + str[1:-1] + first  # new str, where first and last are exchanged
    return new
```

When I submit my answer, CodingBat says:

"Compile problems:
Error:string index out of range"

Comment: vicaashow, what Python version are you using? Your code works out of the box for me (in Python 3.3), except when passing a string that is empty to it.

Comment: @Sg'te'gmuj I am using python 2.7.6. Now it works because of ndpu correction, except when passing an empty string to it.

Comment: Yeah it looks like he forgot a step, it's okay though. Also, just a note: your English is fine, if not perfect. And it's really cool that you're starting so early and it seems like you have a good grasp on it (you started at the same age I did). Keep at it. Also note that KISS isn't meant to be rude or derogatory, it's just a programming philosophy.

Comment: I understood it. People like you motivate me to keep solving problems and programming. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep It Simple Stupid(s):

```
def front_back(str):

    if len(str) <= 1:
        return str

    return str[-1:] + str[1:-1] + str[:1]

print (front_back("abcdef"))
```

You don't need all those temporary variables; Python is magical! This is extending on the point made that you need to check for empty strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should add check for 0 sized strings:

```
def front_back(str): 
  if str:
     if len(str)==1:   #if str is 'a', it should return 'a'
        return str
     else:    # len(str) is greater than one
       first = str[0]        # first character
       last = str[-1]        # last charater
       new = last + str[1:-1] + first  # new str, where first and last are exchanged
       return new
```

Comment: @vicaashow change if str:.. to if not str: return 'SOMETHING' if you need to return something in case if string is empty

Answer (score 0):

It not good Python style or practice to use built in names such `str` in Python.  Hopefully Coding bat will change this at some point:

You can do this problem using only slicing like this:

```
def front_back(s):
    return s[-1:] + (s[:-1] + s[0:1])[1:]
```